# Rails CSV generator - undefined method `collect' for Mon, 17 Jun 2019 14:16:10 CEST +02:00:Time in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got CSV generetor for admin logs. When I run a test I've got an error

> 1) CsvAdminLogData::CsvAdminLogGenerator creates CSV file with proper value
>       Failure/Error: csv << admin_log.created_at
>
> NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `collect' for Mon, 17 Jun 2019 14:16:10 CEST +02:00:Time

```
def call
  CSV.open(target_file, 'w', headers: LOG_HEADERS, encoding: 'UTF-8') do |csv|
    AdminPanelLog.dates_between(start_date, end_date).find_each do |admin_log|
      csv << admin_log.created_at
      csv << admin_log.action_type
      csv << admin_log.admin_email
      csv << admin_log.old_data
      csv << admin_log.new_data
    end
  end
end
```

I've try to something like `admin_log.created_at.to_s` but without any results. In this case I can't use `<<` to add this data to CSV file?

EDIT:

If I comment `# csv << admin_log.action_type` I will get the same error for another row

> Failure/Error: csv << admin_log.action_type
>       NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `collect' for "New":String

Comment: please update question to include full backtrace errors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add `Array`s to `csv` Array, like this:

```
csv << [admin_log.created_at, admin_log.action_type, admin_log.admin_email, admin_log.old_data, admin_log.new_data]
```

Comment: Ok but in that way I will not have headers in my CSV, am I right? should I add them in a different way than before?

Comment: @mr_muscle yes, you should add them manually, before entering this iteration.

Comment: It will work too if I add ` write headers: true` in my `CSV.open(...)` line. Thanks a lot!